# Is there need any other file or code in RFID to unlock windows

Tags: arduino, iot, rfid

Here I upload this code in my Arduino Leonardo circuit but when I scanned my card on RFID sensor windows locked successfully but when I scanned card on lock screen there is error occur that incorrect password enter.

So I want suggestion about update or addition in code.

```
#include <deprecated.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <MFRC522Extended.h>
#include <require_cpp11.h>

#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 2
#define KEY_RETURN 0xB0                 //The hex value for the return key is 0xB0.
 
MFRC522 mfrc522 ( SS_PIN, RST_PIN ) ;
char Enter = KEY_RETURN;                //Return key is declared as Enter.
String readid;
String card1="e9226c15";                //Change this value to the UID of your card.
 
void setup( ) 
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Keyboard.begin();
 SPI.begin();
 mfrc522.PCD_Init();
}

void temp(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize)//function to store card uid as a string datatype.
{
  readid="";
  for(byte i = 0;i<bufferSize; i++)
  {
    readid=readid+String(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
void loop( ) 
{
 if(!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
 {
  return;
 }
 if(!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
 {
  return;
 }
 mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));  // Display card details in serial Monitor.
 temp(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
 if(readid==card1)
 { 
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);              //Press the left windows key.
  Keyboard.press('l');                       //Press the "l" key.
  Keyboard.releaseAll();                     //Release all keys.
  delay (100);
  Keyboard.press(Enter);                     //Press the Enter key.
  Keyboard.release(Enter);                   //Release the Enter key.
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.print("12345");                    // Change this value to your Windows PIN/Password.
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.press(Enter);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
 }
 else
 {
  return;
 } 
}
``
```

Comment: As the comment says you need to change `12345` to your PCs lockscreen password (the password you would enter to unlock your PC).

Comment: This is temporary password and it is same as windows password.

Comment: You can then test the following: Don’t press enter and check if the password entered is correct.